# add the number in list of a dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe. One of the column **u4** is a list. Something like below:

[image]

The number in the list of list is string type. How can I add the numbers in the list.

```
0    60
1    0
2    87.98
.
.
.
```

I tried to use a loop:

```
lists=[]
for row in activity_u_variables.u4:
    total=0
    for i in row:
        total+=i
    lists.append(total)
```

It gave me an error message that TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Any idea?

Comment: `total=0` you are declaring it as a `int` yet adding `total+=i` it with a string `i`

Comment: try `total+=float(i)` As you said, the values are strings. Convert to float

Comment: Instead of the image please copy paste the file..a sample atleast!

Comment: @nikpod I did try total+=float(i). Instead it gave me another error message **TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `0`s present in the DataFrame which are not part of a list. Thus, `for i in row:` fails. If 0 is the only number that is not in the form of a list, you can convert it to `[0]`

Also, `i` is String like you mentioned. You must explicitly convert it to float for `+` operation to work.

Thus, your code must be modified to:

```
lists=[]
for row in activity_u_variables.u4:
    total=0
    if row == 0:
        row = [0]
    for i in row:
        total+=float(i)
    lists.append(total)
```

Comment: Thank you @nikpod. Now it works. I think the issue is because `0` is not part of list.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function which returns the sum if it's possible, or the original value if it isn't.

```
def my_sum(x):
    try:
        return sum(x)
    except TypeError:
        return x
```

and then apply this function to the columns

```
sums = df['u4'].apply(my_sum)
```

if the columns is a string representation of a list you might do something like this

```
def my_sum(x):
    import ast

    if isinstance(x, str):
        x = ast.literal_eval(x)
    try:
        return sum(x)
    except TypeError:
        return x
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out another method. I post here for you guys reference. This function is good if you need to do this process for multiple columns.

```
# create a list_sum function 

def list_sum(s):
     return sum([float(i) for i in `s.split('|')])

# apply the function
activity_u_variables.u4.astype(str).apply(lambda x: list_sum(x))
```